# Using SSL Certificates within Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, ssl-certificate

I would like to learn of alternative **secure** solutions to manage and use SSL certs within Lambda functions/applications

What I have:

- Certificates are stored within Parameter Store.
- ARNs numbers for certificates are added to each lambda environment.

Lambda function:

- Certificates are fetched from Parameter Store.
- A local temp file, with cert inside, is created for use with `requests` functions.

Question:
What can be done to improve current process or is there a better alternative? My additional concern is that we have to repeat temp file creation every time lambda function is called.

Comment: Why do you need certificates in the lambda at all, what requests are you trying to sign any why is that not handled by a load balancer or api gateway?

Comment: lambda is sending requests to a 3rd party. Those request need to have both certificate and a verification ca added. So, I can call Lambda and then send requests to a 3rd party via an api gateway?

Comment: Are you talking about client certificates? Or is the certificate of the target site self-signed which is the reason you need to some manual work? Generally a target HTTPS site should just be callable without any manual SSL certificate work on your end at all. Or do you want certificate pinning??

Comment: Those are self signed certs between 3rd party and myself. Those certs are used as a form of authentication. So, they have to be "pinned" and used with each request. (I never had to thing that hard about certificates before)

Comment: Sounds fine to store the certificate or the CA in a file and specify it during the request call. Depending on the number of lambdas you have running concurrently and for how long it may make sense to cache that certificate and have each lambda execution environment only download it once.

Answer (score 1):

You can upload 3rd-party public certificate in your lambda layer, then config your environemnt to use the certificate.

with java:

```
"JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS", "-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/opt/client_keystore_1.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=mysecretpass"
```

If your certificate is a .cer file, you can use Keytool to create the .jks file

```
keytool -importcert \
-keystore ~/Downloads/client_truststore_1.jks \
-storetype JKS \
-file ~/Downloads/3rd-party-cert.cer \
-keypass mysecretpass \
-storepass mysecretpass \
-alias 3rdpartycert \
-noprompt
```

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/implementing-mutual-tls-for-java-based-aws-lambda-functions/